# Como usar uma mesma instância para várias classes?

Tags: c#

Abaixo eu vou tentar dar um valor ao progressBar que está na classe `Controles`.

O método do `Form1`, irá chamar o método da classe `ManipularProgressBar` para alterar o valor do Controle `ProgressBar` que está na classe `Controles`.

Mas só que.. quando pego o controle progressBar que está na instancia e atribuo um valor, dá a seguinte mensagem: referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

Esse erro ocorre porque estou definindo uma nova instancia de um objeto, aí retorna `null`. Mas só que, eu não sei qual a melhor forma de resolver este problema. Não sei exatamente onde coloco a instancia ou se preciso instanciar.

Estou pensando em transformar a classe `ManipularProgressBar` em estática ou criar uma instância dela global para que todas as classes tenham acesso a um mesmo valor sem resetar.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Controles controls = new Controles();
        ManipularProgressBar mp = new ManipularProgressBar();

        controls.progressBar = this.progressBar1;            
        mp.editProgressBar();
    }
}

public class ManipularProgressBar
{  
    public void editProgressBar()
    {
        Controles controls = new Controles();
        controls.progressBar.Value = 50;
    }
}

public class Controles
{
    public ProgressBar progressBar { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Melhor dizer o que pretende porque este código não parece fazer o menor sentido e criar uma classe estática parece só aumentar a gambiarra. Os nomes de tudo são ruins demais, não dá para ter ideia do que seja isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que faz mais sentido ai, é vc passar o progressBar como parametro no método de edit, pois você esta fazendoa  chamada do edit sem que ele saiba qual progressBar será editada.

```
    controls.progressBar = this.progressBar1;            
    mp.editProgressBar(controls.progressBar);
```

Answer (score -1):

Cara, o problema está na forma como você está abstraindo as coisas...
Olhando especificamente nesse seu cenário, a classe Controle não faz sentido em existir, pois se você recebe uma instancia de um ProgressBar do Form, você poderia simplesmente fazer com que o método editProgressBar recebesse a instancia da Progress e fizesse a alteração do valor. Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Classe1().editProgressBar(this.progressBar1);            
    }    

public class Classe1
{
    public void editProgressBar(ProgressBar _ProgressBar, int valor = 50)
    {
        _ProgressBar.Value = valor;
    }
}
```

Se por algum motivo, você realmente precisa que a classe Controle exista, então a abordagem precisa ser um pouco diferente.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Controle _controle = new Controle();
            _controle._ProgressBar = this.progressBar1;
            new Classe1().editProgressBar(_controle._ProgressBar);            
        }

  public class Controle
    {
        public ProgressBar _ProgressBar { get; set; }
    }
```

Nesse segundo caso, a Classe1 fica do mesmo jeito.

Obvio que esse é só um pseudo-código, mas atende à esse cenário...